# C# Winform How to iterate all panels children inside panel parent

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a parent Panel called "pl_parent" and inside it, there's 3 panel children with names (from left - right) pl_child1, pl_child2, pl_child3.

Im trying to iterate all panel children inside pl_parent when button1 is pressed (pl_child1, pl_child2, pl_child3) with the following code :

```
    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Panel pan in pl_parent)
        {

        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work as expected and I get an error "Error   CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Panel' because 'Panel' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `IEnumerable<Panel>`. The Following code works:

```
IEnumerable<Panel> pnls = pl_parent.Controls.OfType<Panel>();
foreach (Panel pan in pnls)
{
    pan.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
```

To iterate by tab order you can use `IEnumerable<Panel> pnls = pl_parent.Controls.OfType<Panel>().OrderBy(ci => ci.TabIndex);`.

Comment: Yes, this works. But can you explain what does 
'IEnumerable<Panel> pnls = pl_parent.Controls.OfType<Panel>();" do? I dont quite understand it. Thanks!

Comment: I am not most competent in explaining this, therefore please correct me if I am wrong. Basically it creates an instance of `IEnumerable<Panel>` and selects all controls type of `Panel` within pl_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try method Show() for each panel